# .NET Core 3.1 - application stops for no reason - System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException

Tags: asp.net-core

My .NET Core API main loop just stops after a while for no reason

I get an exception

**Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll**

but I cannot find anything relevant in google

- how can I figure what makes my API crash ?
- why is it not caught in my try {} catch ?

```
try
{
    Log.Information("Started application");
    host.Run();  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<runs for 10-20' then gets to next line
    Log.Information("Stopped application");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Log.Fatal(exception, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: If you are on Windows, then you can see further details in windows event viewer > application events as to what is the real issue.

Comment: already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Your Cancelation token throws that exception so somewhere you reach the timeout.
For example when I debug my tests it always was throwing such exception as on the beginning in the async function I put *new CancellationTokenSource(1000 <-timeout defined).Token* There is no problem to catch TaskCanceledException.